# Copy view from storyboard and put programatically in scrollView

Tags: ios, swift, view, storyboard, custom-view

Can I create a custom view in storyboard and than put an array of it programatically in the scroll view? (TableView not working when I put it in scrollView)

Comment: Why do you want this ? TableView has default scrollview inside.

Comment: 100 % agree with @emresancaktar

Comment: No, I need a tableview inside a scrollview, not vice versa, it means I have a scroll view that has other objects inside, besides this tableview..

Comment: You can try to put the table view inside the scroll view, disable table view scroll and set its height to display all cells